# Genicam transport Layer

Tags: camera, ethernet, genicam

I am new to Genicam standard, i having issue on understanding the transport layer for gigE camera. I couldnt find any detail information or guideline on writing a gigE camera transport layer as mostly it is provided by the camera vendor directly. Appreciate if anyone can share some information about this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most widely used transport layer for GigE cameras is the GigEVision protocol. The standard is available as free from the [AIA website](https://www.visiononline.org/vision-standards-details.cfm), but is not open source compatible.

[Aravis](https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis) is a reverse engineered open source implementation of this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Dalsa did provide GigE-V Framework at their [website](https://www.teledynedalsa.com/imaging/support/downloads/package/132/). From the source code provided, there are several function is compile as .so file but it is still manageable to reverse engineer the function in driver. I am working until the camera register part. So it is a good reference to understand gige vision driver and genicam. Below is the result i get:

```
GigE Vision Library GenICam C Example Program (Aug 29 2017)
Copyright (c) 2015, DALSA.
All rights reserved.

[0][22]: 192.168.34.22 , D0:67:E5:2B:B2:3D
[1][26]: 192.168.34.26 , 0C:C4:7A:4C:96:C1
[2][30]: 192.168.34.30 , 00:01:29:65:93:A5
[0][14]: 192.168.128.14 , 3A:F4:E2:F9:AF:F7
4 camera(s) on the network
Please enter selected camera Index:3
Socket Handle success! 
Available Port 8080 
Available Port 8081 
Available Port 8082 
Gev_CreateConnection 
[testGev_CreateConnection]: IP 192.168.128.14 Port 8080
Connected! 
[GevInitCameraRegisters]: supported camera 19
Found Your Camera Model Nano Nano
```